# Trigonometry gymnastics

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

The teacher is as usual jumping a million miles between steps, I appreciate if someone can break down how this step is done:

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
i & j & k \\
-\sin(s)(2+\cos(t)) & \cos(s)(2+\cos(t)) & 0 \\
-\cos(s)\sin(t) & -\sin(s)\sin(t) & \cos(t) \\
\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(s)\cos(t)(2+\cos(t))\\
\sin(s)\cos(t)(2+\cos(t))\\
\sin(t)(2+\cos(t))\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

What trigonometry magic is used to get to that last line $\sin(t)(2+\cos(t))$? I've spent several hours now trying to get it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's abbreviated notation for saying that the coefficient of $i$ is the algebraic complement, that is,
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
\cos s(2+\cos t) & 0 \\
-\sin s\sin t & \cos t
\end{bmatrix}=
\cos s\cos t(2+\cos t)
$$
Similarly, the coefficient of $j$ is
$$
-\det\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin s(2+\cos t) & 0 \\
-\cos s\sin t & \cos t
\end{bmatrix}=
\sin s\cos t(2+\cos t)
$$
and the coefficient of $k$ is
\begin{align}
\det\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin s(2+\cos t) & \cos s(2+\cos t) \\
-\cos s \sin t & -\sin s \sin t
\end{bmatrix}&=
\sin^2s\sin t(2+\cos t)+\cos^2s\sin t(2+\cos t)\\
&=(\sin^2 s+\cos^2s)\sin t(2+\cos t)
\end{align}

You're probably forgetting a “det” in front of the matrix with $i$, $j$ and $k$ (or it's assumed in that context); it's a “formal” determinant, of course.

Comment: You are absolutely right that is it an determinant/curl/rot or whatever one like to call it. It seems I've gotten something wrong in my calculation of $k$, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Remember the identity $$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 $$

Comment: Oh I've tried to use that in every way I can.